# Dynamic selection of content of FlexTable in GWT

Tags: css, html-table, gwt, flextable

I have NxN flextable using GWT, now by default when i select any rows from table then it select it from all column.

I want behavior like if i select rows from first column then it only select from that column only, now if i further drag my mouse to second column then include rows from second column also and so on.

By default i have disable the selection of flextable like below

```
.flexTableStyle {
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

then enable for each column like below

```
.flexTableStyle td:nth-child(1),
.flexTableStyle td:nth-child(2),
.flexTableStyle td:nth-child(3),
.flexTableStyle td:nth-child(4) {
    user-select: text; /* Standard syntax */
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-user-select: text; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: text; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
}
```

But it doesn't help as it have same behaviour.

Any solution?